# Get DOORS Attribute Type via LYO

Tags: java, ibm-doors, oslc, reqif, lyo

I am trying to use LYO (`org.eclipse.lyo.clients:oslc-java-client:2.4.0`) to read requirements from DOORS via OSLC and parse them to ReqIF. I successfully manage to read out a `Requirement` object using this request:

```
        String requirementURL = http://localhost:8080/dwa/rm/urn:rational::1-5efc6f9a4ff877cf-O-2-00000100;
        ClientResponse requirementResponse = oslcOauthClient.getResource(requirementURL, OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
        Requirement requirement = requirementResponse.getEntity(Requirement.class);
```

While doing that, I ran into an issue while trying to parse the Attribute Values. From a DOORS perspective, these are located in `requirement.extendedProperties[x].value`. However, there is a problem. The ReqIF standard defines 7 Attribute Value types that msut be adhered to, such as `ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-INTEGER`, `ATTRIBUTE-VALUE-DATE` etc... Now, for the most part, the objects contained in `requirement.extendedProperties[x].value` are of a clearly mappable type such as `int` or `date`. However, in some cases, they are instead `URI`. Here's some samples or URIs that emerge at this point:

```
http://localhost:8080/dwa/rm/urn:rational::1-5efc6f9a4ff877cf-M-00000100/types/attrDef-1025#1
http://localhost:8080/dwa/rm/acp/urn:rational::1-5efc6f9a4ff877cf-F-00000000/gFgcK1req0%252BQ5gE6yE5YsEZZcDI%253D%250A
http://localhost:8080/dwa/rm/urn:rational::1-5efc6f9a4ff877cf-M-00000100/types/attrDef-10#1
```

Now *I* understand that these URIs point to DOORS resources. The first and third are Enumeration value references, and I don't know what the second one is. However, as far as I understand it, I *should* be able to access the corresponding DOORS resources using these URIs, and then be able to have a look at them to determine what they are, and consequently how to parse them.

However, this is when everything fails, because when I try to make this request:

```
        String uriValue = http://localhost:8080/dwa/rm/urn:rational::1-5efc6f9a4ff877cf-M-00000100/types/attrDef-1025#1;
        ClientResponse response = oslcOauthClient.getResource(uriValue , OslcMediaType.APPLICATION_RDF_XML);
```

...instead of a response containing a usable entity, `response.entity` is of the object type EofSensorInputStream, whereas I would have expected *something like* `EnumValue`, or something.

So, here's the question: Based on that URI that is contained within `requirement.extendedProperties[x].value`, how can I retrieve the resource it points to in order to determine the attribute type that I have to use? Apparently, `oslcOauthClient.getResource` is the wrong thing to use, or I am using it the wrong way. Maybe the second parameter is wrong in this case (even though it works for retrieving the Requirement), but then I have no idea what would be the correct parameter or how to figure it out.

Or to make it even shorter:

So, I figured out that the value of this attribute is the URI `http://localhost:8080/dwa/rm/urn:rational::1-5efc6f9a4ff877cf-M-00000100/types/attrDef-1025#1` .

...now what?